# What modifications/upgrades were done to US MD-80 fleet?

Tags: usa, md-80, modifications

I have often heard stories about how most of the MD-80 fleet that are being retired in the US were modified and upgraded.

What were the modifications or upgrades done?

Comment: Can you link some of this stories?

Comment: It won't be much mechanical.  It's going to be almost all avionics/electronics upgrades, like changing from steam gauges to flat panels, or sometimes structural mods and reinforcements to allow operation to higher hours without unworkable inspection frequency requirements.